# How to call one function from another function in express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, meanjs

```
exports.usersignup= function(req, res) {
console.log('user signed up working')

}
exports.addcustomer= function(req, res) {
console.log('customer added')

}
```

I have two function which  is  exports.usersignup and exports.addcustomer .when i call exports.usersignup function it should call exports.addcustomer
function and it should work the given logic how can i get this done any one help me out.pls dont give down vote i already tried but its not working

Comment: pass **next** variable in the usersignup function and when you want to call addcustomer just use **return next()** statement ;

Comment: pls can you give the example code

Comment: exports.usersignup= function(req, res,next) {
console.log('user signed up working')
return next();
}

Comment: what is your exact route??

Comment: app.route('/auth/usersignup').post(users.usersignup);

Comment: then just change it to app.route('/auth/usersignup').post(users.usersignup,users.addcustomer); and don't forget to write usersignup as i mention in above comment

Answer (score 3):

Here is a naïve solution:

```
exports.usersignup = function (req, res) {
  console.log('usersignup')
  exports.addcustomer()
}

exports.addcustomer = function (req, res) {
  console.log('addcustomer')
}
```

A better solution would be to utilize [**Express middleware**](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html):

```
// customer.js
// ...

exports.usersignup = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('usersignup')
  next()
}
exports.addcustomer = function (req, res) {
  console.log('addcustomer')
}

// app.js
// ...

var express = require('express')
var customer = require('./customer.js')
var app = express()
app.post('/user', customer.usersignup, customer.addcustomer)
```

Comment: this is a better way, but when you are doing db operations like ```addcustomer``` then it should be in different ```.js``` file which could be imported where ever it is required and used rather than passing next() for saving the user.

Comment: i want to pass req.body to customer

Comment: i am getting error F:\meanjs\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:31
            throw err;
            ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:346:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (F:\meanjs\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:666:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (F:\meanjs\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:146:12)

Comment: @komal You'll get that error if you call `res.json`/`res.sendStatus` or a similar function in _both_ functions.

Comment: @komal Please update your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and I'll try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

pass next variable in the usersignup function and when you want to call addcustomer just use return next() statement

Comment: pls give full answer

Comment: You can use @Alex Booker's answer because me answer is same as he mentioned above

Comment: if needed then we can take this conversation in chat

Comment: i want to pass req.body to customer function

Comment: F:\meanjs\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:31
            throw err;
            ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:346:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (F:\meanjs\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:666:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (F:\meanjs\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:146:12)
    i am geting error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112778/discussion-between-atul-agrawal-and-komal).